# Angular.JS Redirect not logged in user

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to redirect an user that is not logged in back to the login page, but I do not know how to implement this in my case.

I have:

- MainController: attached to body tag - available in the whole app
- AccountController: attached via routing to account.html
- LoginController: attached via routing to login.html
- UserService: user object from the server and refresh() method to repopulate it from server

MainController triggers refresh() of UserService on startup and every 10 seconds.
Now I want to redirect an user that wants to access account.html to login.html if he is not logged in. Therefore I want to check the user variable of my UserService inside AccountController:

```
var init = function() {
  if(UserService.user==null) {
    //redirect
  }
}; init();
```

Problem is that the user variable is not populated at first because MainController gets data from server async.

What is the best way to make this work? I could use events to tell AccountController that data is available. I could also set up a while loop in AccountController and wait until data is available.

//EDIT: I could call refresh() in the init() method of every controller I have (using deferred to make the check for user variable afterwards), but than I have to duplicate this code in every controller.

Comment: I would recommend `TypeScript` for coding JS. You could easily create a `BaseController` class wich all controlers could extend from. There you could call your `checkUserLogin()` without having to write this on every class.

Answer (score 0):

Don't start the refresh cycle until the defer from the get user have resolved.

Then use the location provider: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: But how to get the deferred? The refresh() method gets called in MainController, so this controller has the defer. How to check for it in AccountController?

Comment: You could use the $rootScope, but it might be better to use the approach that Ita answered with.

Answer (score 0):

I think a common approach is to wrap the `$http` service and redirect the user if a `401 - unauthorized` response is received from the server.

Using an example from https://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/:

```
//Works for 1.1.x versions. 1.0.x is similar and can be figured out using code comments
myapp.factory('myHttpResponseInterceptor',['$q','$location',function($q,$location){
  return {
    response: function(response){
      return promise.then(
        function success(response) {
        return response;
      },
      function error(response) {
        if(response.status === 401){
          $location.path('/signin');
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else{
          return $q.reject(response); 
        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
//Http Intercpetor to check auth failures for xhr requests
myapp.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpResponseInterceptor');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Create a function `checkLogin` in your `UserService`
2. On every controller initialization, call this function (you could use `$route` and `resolve` for that too)
3. Check if user is logged in (a variable, a `localStorage` or a cookie) and if user is on `/login` page. If it is on login page and logged in, you can take him out of there (go to `/homeLoggedIn`). Use `$location` service for that. If user is not logged in and he is not in `/login` page, get him there!
4. Add an http interceptor to check for 401 responses. If this happens, remove the cookies, variables ou `localStorage` JSON objects and directs user to `login`.

Comment: This is a good idea. But how can I call the method checkLogin in every controller I have, without duplicating this call in every controller? For now I call the method checkLogin only in MainController - but then I can't access defer inside e.g. AccountController. If I call checkLogin in AccountController instead, I have to setup this check in every controller. Basically I'm searching for a way to call checkLogin only once (e.g. in MainController) while being able to check this defer inside all other controllers. Do you understand me?

Comment: Yes I do. That's why I use `TypeScript` with `extend` to inherit classes in this situation. It translates to nice JS and ECMA3. Another way is using `$route` and `resolve` for that. Your resolve promise would check if user is looged in on pages that login is needed and change route to the login page. You could also monitor that on `$routeChangeStart` to not allow users to change pages that login is required.

Comment: Check this: https://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/urls-routing-and-partials/listening-on-route-changes-to-implement-a-login-mechanism.html